# How can I find the parent table using sequence in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
select SEQUENCE_OWNER, SEQUENCE_NAME from ALL_SEQUENCES
```

Let's assume that the above code will give me the following result.

```
<Table Name: ALL_SEQUENCES> 
SEQUENCE_OWNER      SEQUENCE_NAME 
schema1             table1_name_seq       
schema1             table2_name_seq       
schema2             table1_name_seq
```

I am pretty sure every sequence has a corresponding parent table in which the sequence is for. So, I would like to find the parent table using the **sequence_name**. For example, I should find table name **schema1.table1** if I know the sequence name **table1_name_seq** with sequence owner **schema1**.

SUBSTRING or REPLACE function to re-format string is not recommended because **sequence_name** does not follow 'good consistent naming standard' and I do not have access to change it.

I can't find any information regarding this matter. Your help would be much appreciated!

Comment: There's only a _virtual_ relationship (developer made) between `sequence` and a `table`.. So having said this, unless we have a naming standard there's no way around..

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar Hmm.. that is what I expected.. T^T

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short Answer: It is not a one to one relationship between sequences and tables.

Long(er) Answer:

You can use a single sequence in for multiple tables (using multiple triggers, for example).

You would have to search through database object code for the sequence name to see all the places where it could be used.

Even then you could miss out because you can really get the next value from a sequence in any app using PLSQL code.

Comment: This is correct, unlike in SQL Server where an identity is tied to a particular table, Oracle Sequences are distinct database objects that are only related to a table when a developer uses that sequence for only one table...there is no hard connection between them

Comment: Even though I assume that there is only one to one relationship between sequences and tables, there is no way to do this without making naming standard?

Comment: No, you cannot add a relationship. Naming standards are a possibility. Or maybe add a hack with `COMMENT ON TABLE`?

Answer (score 0):

There no relation between a sequence and a table stored in database sys tables. You can create one though